# Trailing space when using a() in R Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'd like to show this static text in the user interface of a shiny app:

> The source of the data is source.org.

and make source.org a hyperlink.

I added this line of code to my app.R file:

```
p("The source of the data is ", a(href = "http://source.org", "source.org"), ".")
```

but if I run the app, I get a space between the hyperlink and the dot. Like this:

> The source of the data is source.org .

How can I remove the trailing space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid predefined shiny html tags such as p(), a() etc. It is much easier to use any html attributes using `HTML()` just writing those attributes inline. 
 In this case:

```
HTML("<p>The source of the data is <a href = 'http://source.org'>source.org.</a></p>")
```